# code review: is it acceptable to induce an infinite loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Stumbled across this coding challenge today and, the goal is to **check if n is a power of two**. Not all too happy with my solution although it does seem pass all tests.

For one, it doesn't really seem to match the Pseudo code written before it and when trying to compare n to a number greater than those used in the tests ie: `while n < 10:` I am hit with an infinite loop.

Having trouble wrapping my head around this one!

I've heard of purposefully inducing an indefinite loop; is this some sort of abstract rendition of that concept?

```
def is_power_of_two(n):
  # Check if the number can be divided by two without a remainder
  while n % 2 != n:
    n = n / 2
  # If after dividing by two the number is 1, it's a power of two
  if n == 1:
    return True
  return False
```

```
print(is_power_of_two(0)) # Should be False
print(is_power_of_two(1)) # Should be True
print(is_power_of_two(8)) # Should be True
print(is_power_of_two(9)) # Should be False
```

Comment: I don't think this is infinite - n is repeatedly divided by two - it will eventually reach 1 or a number less than 1 (and the loop will end).

Comment: I don't understand what the title of your post has to do with the actual problem you are facing.

Comment: A function that's supposed to return a value should never have an infinite loop. Infinite loops are only appropriate for applications that run continuously, like servers and advertising kiosks.

Comment: In the abstract, "when is it acceptable to use infinite loops" is probably for Software Engineering Stack Exchange. "I'm not happy with my current code; should it use an infinite loop?" is for Code Review Stack Exchange.

Comment: `n % 2 != n` is not doing what the comment above says it does. I think you are asking a quite abstract question, when you really should be asking "what is wrong with my code".

Comment: If you want to test if it can be divided by 2 without a remainder, use `n % 2 == 0`

Comment: welcome to python @icecream. You can do anything you want here, but with great power comes great responsibility. Try to `import this`

Comment: For the edit: If it makes sense to use an infinite loop, then do it. I garuentee that it wont loop for _that_ long. Something will stop it eventually

Comment: To give an example where this code goes wrong: `is_power_of_two(9007199254740993)`

Comment: @trincot looks good to me! :) 64 bit has another 3 decimal places until the problem needs to be solved. Hopefully it's being ran on modern hardware

Comment: @AnthonyL An infinite loop is actually `while not heat_death_of_the_universe():`

Comment: @trincot updating now to a better suited title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code seems to work well for many inputs, but it relies on floating point numbers, by applying a (non-integer) division by 2. If in the end this nicely ends up with `n` being 1, then indeed the original number was a power of 2.

However, because of floating point limitations, this will break far large enough inputs. You'll get false positives.

For instance:

```
is_power_of_two((1<<80) + 1)
```

This should return `False`, as there are clearly two 1-bits in this number. But your function will return `True`, as if the input had been `1<<80`.

To get a correct implementation, you should use integer division (`//`) and keep looping as long as the remainder is 0.

And to the topic of infinite loops: it could not loop infinitely for because `n` becomes smaller by the division, and eventually, it will get below the value of 2, when `n % 2 == n`.

Even when `n` is negative... in that case it will remain negative by the division, but again because of floating point limitations, the division will eventually give 0, and at that moment the loop condition is fulfilled.

The integer-based version, could loop forever if the input is 0, and would need protection for that case. We can use the opportunity to also capture negative inputs:

```
  if n <= 0:
    return False
  while n % 2 == 0:
    n = n // 2
```

Now the above test case will return the correct result.

Note that you can do this without explicit loop, using some bit wise operators:

```
  return n > 0 and (n & -n == n)
```

Or possibly more readable:

```
  return n > 0 and (1 << (n.bit_length() - 1) == n)
```

Answer (score 2):

This algorithm can actually be solved without a loop at all.

If you choose to use bit shifting, the algorithm can look like:

```
def is_power_two(n):
    if n < 1:
        return False
    return n == (1 << n.bit_length() - 1)
```

Give a number `n`, you can use a bit shift of `1 << number of bits - 1` along with a equality check to `n`. If the number is a power of two, zero (`True`) is returned, otherwise a non-zero value (`False`) is returned.

---

Example:

The number 8 occupies four bits: `0b1000`. A bit left shifted three (`1 << 3`) with an equality check to 8 (`0b1000 == 8`) returns True.  However, the number 10 also occupies four bits: `0b1010`. Yet, a bit left shifted three (`0b1000`), an equality check with 8 (`0b1010 == 8`) returns False.

---

Testing:

```
for i in range(65):
    print(i, is_power_two(i))

0 False
1 True  # 2**0
2 True
3 False
4 True
5 False
6 False
7 False
8 True
9 False
...
62 False
63 False
64 True
```

Comment: Versions without that extra `if`: `return 0 < n == (1 << n.bit_length() - 1)`, `return 2 * n == 1 << n.bit_length()`.

Answer (score 0):

This works for smaller numbers:

```py
def is_power_of_two(n):
    while n > 1:
        n /= 2
    return n == 1

print(is_power_of_two(0)) # False
print(is_power_of_two(1)) # True
print(is_power_of_two(8)) # True
print(is_power_of_two(9)) # False
```

But for bigger numbers, its accuracy is compromised by Python's floating point accuracy. So, you can use this:

```py
def is_power_of_two(n):
    return bin(n).count('1') == 1

print(is_power_of_two(0)) # False
print(is_power_of_two(1)) # True
print(is_power_of_two(8)) # True
print(is_power_of_two(9)) # False

print(is_power_of_two(2**54))     # True
print(is_power_of_two(2**54 - 1)) # False
print(is_power_of_two(2**54 + 1)) # False
```

This works by using the fact that a number is a power of two if in binary it has no other 1s after the leading digit (e.g. 2 = 10, 4
= 100, 8 = 1000, etc.)

Comment: This only works for small powers of 2 due to finite floating point precision. For example, `is_power_of_two(2**54 - 1) ` is `True`

Comment: @Brian, realistically, when are you ever going to need to check if `2**54 - 1` is a power of 2?

Comment: @TheThonnu - While I understand your motive, that’s really beside the point.  Either the algorithm is accurate, or it’s not.

Comment: @Brian, I have updated my answer with a solution which works for bigger numbers

Comment: @S3DEV, what do you think of this one's accuracy?